# How to remove error messages in the coding window?

Tags: xcode

I pressed Build before I was done coding my class, and Xcode is showing me a bunch of red errors, which are obviously because I'm not done.

How do I get rid of the errors so they are not showing up in my coding window?

Comment: I'm just learning Xcode myself, and I find it extremely annoying that these "helpful" bubbles pop up and obscure the text I'm trying to fix!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**XCode 4:**
<kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or Editor → Issues → (uncheck) Show All Issues

**Older Versions:**
<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or View → Message Bubbles → Hide All

Answer (score 6):

**XCode 7**: Preferences (⌘,) > General.

Under Issues uncheck "Show live issues"

Comment: None of the others work...Why isn't everyone upvoting this? haha.

Answer (score 4):

double click on the bubble works too

Comment: In Xcode7 double clicking the error doesn't make it disappear.

Answer (score 0):

On Xcode Preferences (⌘,) > Building, set "Never" to Show Message Bubbles during builds